# Chaining a variable number of promises synchronously that share a resource in Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, lighthouse

I'm trying to make use of [Chrome lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/readme.md#using-programmatically) to check a number of urls from a list. I can do this with the one url successfully using their sample code.

```
function launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(url, opts, config = null) {
  return chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: opts.chromeFlags}).then(chrome => {
    opts.port = chrome.port;
    return lighthouse(url, opts, config).then(results => {
      // use results.lhr for the JS-consumeable output
      // https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/types/lhr.d.ts
      // use results.report for the HTML/JSON/CSV output as a string
      // use results.artifacts for the trace/screenshots/other specific case you need (rarer)
      return chrome.kill().then(() => results.lhr)
    });
  });
}
```

However, I would like to check multiple urls. This will require creating the browser window with `chromeLauncher.launch`, executing the `lighthouse` function on each url, and then finally calling `chrome.kill()` on the window, before returning the results.

Initially, I tried solving this using `Promise.all`

```
  return chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: opts.chromeFlags}).then(chrome => {
    opts.port = chrome.port;

    const checks = urls.map((url) => {
      console.log('checking', url)
      return lighthouse(url, opts, config)
    })

    return Promise.all(checks).then((results) => {
      return chrome.kill().then(() => results)
    })
  });
```

but since each call to `lighthouse` uses a shared resource they must wait for the previous call to return before continuing, whereas Promise.all tries make all the lighthouse calls in parallel, and then resolves. This doesn't work with the single shared browser resource.

Then I tried experimenting with using a reducer, with the chrome launcher promise as the initial value.

```
  const checks = urls.reduce((previous, url) => {
    return previous.then((previousValue) => {
      return lighthouse(url, opts, config)
    })
  }, chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: opts.chromeFlags}))

  checks
    .then((results) => {
      console.log('something')
      return chrome.kill()
    })
    .then((results) => results.lhr)
```

but this also doesn't work when calling the lighthouse function, but I think this is the correct approach to calling a chain of promises synchronously.

Does anyone have any suggestions where I'm going wrong, or what else I could try?

Comment: Use async/await

Comment: "Promise.all tries make all the lighthouse calls in parallel" no, you call `lighthouse(...)` synchronously in the `.map` loop, it doesn't matter how you wait for the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With async await:

```
const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

async function launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(urls, opts, config = null) {
    const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: opts.chromeFlags})
    opts.port = chrome.port;
    const results = [];
    for (const url of urls) {
         results.push(await lighthouse(url, opts, config));
    }
    await chrome.kill();
    return results;
}

const opts = {
    chromeFlags: ['--show-paint-rects']
};

// Usage:
const urls = ['http://www.google.de', 'http://www.heise.de'];
launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(urls, opts).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Classic:

```
const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

function launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(urls, opts, config = null) {
    return chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: opts.chromeFlags}).then(chrome => {
        opts.port = chrome.port;

        const results = [];
        return urls.reduce((p, url) => {
            return p.then(() => {
                return lighthouse(url, opts, config).then((data) => {
                    results.push(data);
                    return results;
                });
            });
        }, Promise.resolve())
            .then(() => chrome.kill())
            .then(() => results)
    });
}

const opts = {
    chromeFlags: ['--show-paint-rects']
};

// Usage:
const urls = ['http://www.google.de', 'http://www.heise.de'];
launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(urls, opts).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
})
```

Or using a library like Bluebird:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

function launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(urls, opts, config = null) {
    return chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: opts.chromeFlags}).then(chrome => {
        opts.port = chrome.port;

        return Promise.mapSeries(urls, url => lighthouse(url, opts, config))
            .then((results) => chrome.kill().then(() => results))
    });
}

const opts = {
    chromeFlags: ['--show-paint-rects']
};

// Usage:
const urls = ['http://www.google.de', 'http://www.heise.de'];
launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(urls, opts).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Thank-you for this! Your classic one doesn't kill the chrome instance tho.

Comment: So still any open question here @purpletonic ?